# jquery marquee not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This a code that uses jquery marquee function.This code for works perfectly well in IE and mozilla firefox but it is not working in chrome.So plz tell me how to fix this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>scroll</title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.marquee.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" style="width:99%;min-height:100px;">

       <img src="street cartoon.jpg">

</div>
<div id="scroll" style="width:99%;min-height:100px;overflow:hidden;border:solid black thin;position:absolute;">

       <img src="scroll.jpg" style="margin-top: 25px;">

</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scroll').marquee({
       speed:28000,
       gap: 0,
       delayBeforeStart:0,
       direction: 'left',
       duplicated: true
    });

});
```

Comment: Make test case in http://jsfiddle.net/. And community can help you.

Comment: The marquee is not supported in modern html. I suggest you to use  [jScroller](http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/fqg9d/

Working fine at my end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scroll').marquee({
        speed: 28000,
        gap: 0,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: 'left',
        duplicated: true
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you so much.But can u tell me how can i reduce the gap between the two tickers also how to increase the speed.

Comment: use `speed` and `gap` attributes.

Comment: This worked for me but only the default marquee movement. Adding speed, gap, delayBeforeStart, duplicated, etc. didn't work.